# PERROR torsocks: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)

Tags: python, ubuntu, tor, socks

Sometimes,if not often,the IP address assigned to me by TOR does not work. Is there a way to choose the exit IP numbers where my traffic should exit the Tor network ? I've found a script that tells to be able to change the TOR IP number exit node in a specific time frame. It's called "auto-change-tor-ip" ; unfortunately it does not work. The IP number does not change at all. What I did has been to create a list of IP numbers generated using these websites :

https://www.dan.me.uk/tornodes

https://github.com/SecOps-Institute/Tor-IP-Addresses

I put them inside a text file called "listip.txt" that I have saved inside the directory /home/user/Downloads/auto-change-tor-ip/

After that I tried to run the script called "auto-change-tor-ip" that you can find here :

https://github.com/noobpk/auto-change-tor-ip/

This is the source code of the script :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import time
import os
import re
import sys
import socks
import socket
import urllib.request
from log import *
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all()

print('''\033[1;31m \n
              _             _       
             | |           (_)      
   __ _ _   _| |_ ___  _ __ _ _ __  
  / _` | | | | __/ _ \| '__| | '_ \ 
 | (_| | |_| | || (_) | |  | | |_) |
  \__,_|\__,_|\__\___/|_|  |_| .__/ 
                             | |    
                             |_|    
    Automatically Change Tor Ip Address #noobteam
''')

print("\033[1;34m[*]___author___: @noobpk\033[1;37m")
print("\033[1;34m[*]___version___: 1.3 alpha\033[1;37m")
print("")


def detect_platform():
    try:
        platforms = {
            'linux': 'Linux',
            'linux1': 'Linux',
            'linux2': 'Linux',
            'darwin': 'OS X',
        }
        logger.info("[*] Detect Platform")
        if sys.platform not in platforms:
            logger.error("[x_x] Your platform currently does not support.")
            sys.exit(0)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(
            "[x_x] Something went wrong, please check your error message.\n Message - {0}".format(e))


def check_exists_tor_ip(ipTor):
    with open('listip.txt', 'r') as read_obj:
        for line in read_obj:
            if ipTor in line:
                return True
            else:
                return False


def check_runon_linux():
    try:
        logger.info("[+] Check Requirement")
        istor = os.system('command -v tor')
        istorsocks = os.system('command -v torsocks')
        isprivoxy = os.system('command -v privoxy')
        file_listip = os.path.isfile("listip.txt")
        if (os.geteuid() != 0):
            logger.error(
                "[x_x] You need to have root privileges to run this script")
            sys.exit(0)
        if (istor != 0):
            logger.info("[+] Installing Tor")
            os.system('apt-get install tor -y')
            check_runon_linux()
        if (istorsocks != 0):
            logger.info("[+] Installing TorSocks")
            os.system('apt-get install torsocks -y')
            check_runon_linux()
        if (isprivoxy != 0):
            logger.info("[+] Installing Privoxy")
            os.system('apt-get install privoxy -y')
            check_runon_linux()
        if (file_listip == False):
            logger.info("[+] Creating File listip.txt")
            open("listip.txt", "w")
            check_runon_linux()
        else:
            logger.info("[*] Tor has been installed")
            logger.info("[*] TorSocks has been installed")
            logger.info("[*] Privoxy has been installed")
            logger.info("[*] File listip.txt has been created")
            startservice_linux()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(
            "[x_x] Something went wrong, please check your error message.\n Message - {0}".format(e))


def startservice_linux():
    try:
        logger.info("[*] Current IP Addresss")
        currentip = os.system(
            "wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain ; echo")
        logger.info("[*] Start service Tor")
        os.system("service tor start")
        time.sleep(2)
        logger.info("[*] Start service Privoxy")
        os.system("service privoxy start")
        time.sleep(2)
        logger.info("[*] Add to your browsers HTTP Proxy 127.0.0.1:8118")
        logger.info("[*] Access Privoxy Manager http://p.p/")
        logger.info("[*] Set time stamp")
        sec = int(
            input("[?] Time to auto change ip by second (default 600s):") or "600")
        loop = int(input("[?] Number of loop (default 144):") or "144")
        for i in range(loop):
            logger.info("[*] Change New IP")
            os.system("service tor restart")
            time.sleep(2)
            currentip = os.system(
                "torsocks wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain ; echo")
            socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
            socket.socket = socks.socksocket
            url = 'http://ipecho.net/plain'
            request = urllib.request.Request(url)
            request.add_header('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0')
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
            newip = response.read().decode('utf-8')
            if check_exists_tor_ip(newip):
                restart_tor_service_linux()
            else:
                f = open('listip.txt', 'a+')
                f.write(newip + '\n')
                logger.info("[*] Successfully - Your IP has been Changed")
                logger.info("[*] New IP Addresss:")
                print(newip)
            time.sleep(sec)
        logger.info("[#] The loop has finished refreshing it")
        stopservice_linux()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(
            "[x_x] Something went wrong, please check your error message.\n Message - {0}".format(e))


def restart_tor_service_linux():
    logger.warning("Your IP Already Exist - Request New IP")
    os.system("service tor restart")
    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket
    url = 'http://ipecho.net/plain'
    request = urllib.request.Request(url)
    request.add_header('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0')
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    newip = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    if check_exists_tor_ip(newip):
        restart_tor_service_linux()
    else:
        f = open('listip.txt', 'a+')
        f.write(newip + '\n')
        logger.info("[*] Successfully - Your IP has been Changed")
        logger.info("[*] New IP Addresss:")
        print(newip)


def stopservice_linux():
    try:
        logger.info("[*] Stop service Tor")
        os.system("service tor stop")
        time.sleep(2)
        logger.info("[*] Stop service Privoxy")
        os.system("service privoxy stop")
        os.system("clear")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(
            "[x_x] Something went wrong, please check your error message.\n Message - {0}".format(e))


def main():
    try:
        detect_platform()
        if (sys.platform == 'darwin'):
            logger.info("[*] Darwin - MAC OS-X")
            check_runon_osx()
        if (sys.platform == 'linux') | (sys.platform == 'linux1') | (sys.platform == 'linux2'):
            logger.info("[*] Linux - KALI LINUX - UBUNTU")
            check_runon_linux()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logger.warning("[#] KeyboardInterrupt")
    if (sys.platform == 'darwin'):
        stopservice_osx()
    if (sys.platform == 'linux') | (sys.platform == 'linux1') | (sys.platform == 'linux2'):
        stopservice_linux()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
        logger.error("[x_x] Autorip requires Python 3.x")
    else:
        main()
```

But in my case it didn't work. As I said,the IP never changes (I'm running Ubuntu 23.10).

This is what happens,instead :

```
[*] Detect Platform
[INFO] - [*] Linux - KALI LINUX - UBUNTU
[INFO] - [+] Check Requirement
/usr/sbin/tor
/usr/bin/torsocks
/usr/sbin/privoxy
[INFO] - [*] Tor has been installed
[INFO] - [*] TorSocks has been installed
[INFO] - [*] Privoxy has been installed
[INFO] - [*] File listip.txt has been created
[INFO] - [*] Current IP Addresss
71.35.27.189
[INFO] - [*] Start service Tor
[INFO] - [*] Start service Privoxy
[INFO] - [*] Add to your browsers HTTP Proxy 127.0.0.1:8118
[INFO] - [*] Access Privoxy Manager http://p.p/
[INFO] - [*] Set time stamp
[?] Time to auto change ip by second (default 600s):30
[?] Number of loop (default 144):
[INFO] - [*] Change New IP

**PERROR torsocks[44152]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)**

[INFO] - [*] Successfully - Your IP has been Changed
[INFO] - [*] New IP Addresss:
71.35.27.189
    
    ^CKeyboardInterrupt
```

These are the parameters that I'm using on the configuration files :

/etc/tor/torrc:

```
RunAsDaemon 1
ORPort 62464
Nickname superman
BridgeRelay 1
```

/etc/tor/torsocks.conf:

```
TorAddress 127.0.0.1
TorPort 9150
OnionAddrRange 127.42.42.0/24
```

On my router I opened ports : 62464 ; 9150 ; 9050 ; 9100 ; 8118 ; but I'm not able to fix the error.

Someone can help me to fix it ? thanks.